# Long 19 Digit string at the end of the URL / 404 magento 1.9

Tags: magento

We use a tracking site called Woopra (https://www.woopra.com) and we have started to notice that quite a few of our users are encountering 404's. However these 404's are different to the normal 404's I have seen before.

These 404's are in the format of `www.example.co.uk/xxxxxxx_0000_0000000` where `x` is a letter and `0` is a number. all of the 404's follow this pattern and are usually 19 digits long.

With these 404's only one person has ever found that 404 so it seems like each 404 is unique to the user. Also, these 404's are only ever encountered by going to them directly via a bookmark or entering it in.

Do you think this could just be a bot or do you think it is something to be concerned about and look into more?

Comment: Yeah, those things do a pretty good job of killing Magento. AddThis tries to do the same thing with the same results when they attempt to track bookmarked links. Bookmarked/cited link tracking has proven to be a major non-starter with Magento. Turn it off.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?